# routing error when requesting http://localhost:3000/file2.html [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

create a blank Rails application and put two files under public foler: file1.html and file2.html.

The contents of file is this

```
<h1>Post</h1>
<form action='/file2.html' class='openid' method='POST'>
          <input name='openid_username' type='text' />
          <input type='submit' value='Login' />
</form>
<h1>GET</h1>
 <form action='/file2.html' class='openid' method='GET'>
          <input name='openid_username' type='text' />
          <input type='submit' value='Login' />
  </form>
```

If I click on sumbit for the first form I get

```
No route matches "/file2.html" with {:method=>:post}):
```

When I do a get request it works fine. Why is that? I tried this with both webrick and mongrel and the behavior is same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a route to handle the post. If you run "rake routes" in the root of your project, it will give you a list of all of the routes currently setup and if it's a blank rails project then there will not be a route to handle the post to your file2.html ( although you don't really want to be posting to a static file in public, you should be posting to a controller ). The GET works because it is simply being treated as a static file fetch.

Try http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Does it mean that a POST request is never handled by apache or webserver. In this case I assumed that the request will be handled by webserver and rails will not even come in picture.

Comment: That's going to depend on how your servers are setup, but you mentioned webrick and mongrel, so if you're running on a dev box and point your browser at something like http://localhost:3000/file1.html, then your /file2.html will become http://localhost:3000/file2.html and be served by the rails process. Which is why you are getting that ( rails ) routing error message.